# Tooltip for individual points created using THREE.PointCloud in Autodesk forge

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I followed [this](http://www.keanw.com/2017/01/implementing-tooltips-for-individual-points-in-a-point-cloud-in-the-forge-viewer.html) blog for adding tooltip for each point implemented using **Three.PointCloud**. I used world2Screen to get the location of individual points and tried using this

**elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y)**

but continuously only get canvas as the output (and thus tooltip at a fixed position) instead at the clicked/hovered point.

Anyone who has may be implemented this and knows any work around.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to the blog, the `document.elementFromPoint()` is used to check if the cursor isn’t over the canvas. If you want to capture the hit point of the mouse clicked one, your own raycaster can help in this case. For example:

```
var x =  ((event.clientX - viewer.canvas.offsetLeft) / viewer.canvas.width) * 2 - 1;
var y = -((event.clientY - viewer.canvas.offsetTop) / viewer.canvas.height) * 2 + 1;    
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 0.5).unproject(this.camera);
this.raycaster.set(this.camera.position, vector.sub(this.camera.position).normalize());
var nodes = this.raycaster.intersectObject( this.pointCloud );
```

In the above code snippet, the `event` object is from the mouse clicking event, see here for detail: https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt/blob/master/docs/markupExt.js#L48